# How can I embed telegram video on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, video, telegram, embed

I want to embed telegram video on my website. Is that possible to do?

I am trying to embed telegram video on my website

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: they support embedding a public post, but are not really set up to act as a video hosting service https://core.telegram.org/widgets/post